# Android phone not detecting the RFD22102 RFduino DIP

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, detection, rfduino

I'm using the RFDuinoTest app to test the module, but it is not getting detected by any of the android devices. 
Two of the devices I've tried this on are:
-Samsung Galaxy Grand 2
-Nexus 7 Tablet

I've also tested the module with iphone 5 and it works fine. There aren't any issues in programming it either, and I've tried both with Windows and Mac.

Is there a chance that this is because of some problem with the android devices and not with the module? Or should I just assume that the module is damaged?

Comment: I'd say there is something with BLE implementation & APIs you're using on the Android side. If iPhone detects it there is no reason to think the device is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

To simply test the ability to connect and interact with the rfduino from your mobile device, use a BLE smart device scanner. Try [BLE Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner) for Android.

I found myself in the same predicament when attempting to use the RFdunioTest app for Arduino. I do not know why that app does not pick up surrounding rfduinos.